# Where is the default location of "open" files downloads (Internet Explorer)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer-9

I wasn't able to find out where files get downloaded when I click open when downloading. Where do they get downloaded to?

Comment: usually to C:\Users\<username>\Downloads, can be configured View downloads - Options (free translated from german ;-))

Answer (score 0):

By default:

```
C:\Users\UserName\Downloads\
```

or

```
%Userprofile%\Downloads
```

You can check it on your machine easily by going to Gear icon in IE, then 'View Downloads'.
In the window that opens, click "Options" at the bottom left of the window and then Browse in a second new windows to see the path.